# JW Player does not play all videos from a playlist on mobile

Tags: android, ios, video, youtube, jwplayer

JW Player plays the playlist. The playlist has around 200 videos. The videos are from Youtube. On the computer, it works great. The problem is for mobile devices. On iPhone 6 player plays only the first 4 videos. The same problem has devices with Android.

link: http://www.americantravelshow.com/watch

Comment: What iOS and Android versions?

Comment: iOS 8, Android 4.1.2

Comment: Are any of the items not YouTube?

Comment: No all of them are from YouTube. Only difference between them is URL to youtube. Types of URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hMANYwR7q8, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmZJB7sp2UM&feature=youtu.be, http://youtu.be/bXZoWeB8Fpg.

First two URL are https and the last type is http.

Comment: Does it matter if they have the same urls?

Comment: No. I try playlist consist of the same urls and everytime only 4 videos were played. Do you have any ideas? I need to make it work soon :(.

Comment: Try to make a simple embed of just the playlist. No titles / descriptions / url encoding.

Comment: Ok there is just the playlist: http://www.americantravelshow.com/videoplayer 

But now it plays only first video on iOS8.

Comment: Why are you using sources when you only have one source?

Comment: This is an issue when using multiple YouTube videos back to back on mobile. It doesn't happen with MP4.

Comment: Spotted one thing with your web page: after a video is done playing, player window goes off the screen and comes back. I think every time it's a new instance of the quicktime and since you can't have more than 4 on the page, after 4 items ios wouldn't create a new one. If my assumption is right it's an issue with the way the player handles youtube (and @EthanJWPlayer is right, it's not happening if you play mp4 videos)

Comment: Ok. So there is only one solution - non YouTube videos, right?

Comment: @user2445201 either that or try to contact JW support directly